# CakePHP hidden edit fields

Tags: security, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, hidden-field, postdata

I just started using the CakePHP framework, 2.0 to be precise. I read most of the documentation and examples and came across the blog tutorial.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html#editing-posts
In the "edit post" section of the tutorial I saw they were using a hidden field to remember the post id. Isn't this bad practice because of client side modifications?

The way I handled this is remove the hidden field, and when the form is submitted add the post id to the POST data before saving and validating it. Is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: How do you know which post ID to use?

Comment: Well, I used the example to edit a user instead of a post. So I get the Id of the logged in user from the Auth component: $this->Auth->user('id');

Comment: That's the best way to go when the user is authorized to edit only *one* record in the database, but what about when they can edit more than one?

Comment: Try changing it and see if its "Insecure direct object reference".  Why would you even think to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, thats pretty much the right way if you are concerned about tampering with the data.
if the record belongs to a certain user you need to make sure that this user can't just replace the id with the one of an other user's record.
the security component does NOT help here either (at least for some aspects).

read more about it here:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/09/21/saving-model-data-and-security/

Comment: The SecurityComponent won't allow the client to alter hidden fields.

Comment: ok, right. the documentation for 2.0 states that new behavior.

Comment: you may still use the above approach (not using hidden fields and using the passed first param which is also the id) if you dont want to (or can't - ajax for example) use the security component. otherwise I would then recommend wylie's answer.

Answer (score 1):

SecurityComponent will help with hidden fields. It will black-hole any request that it detects contains tampered-with hidden inputs, but it won't do anything for drop-down inputs. You can crack some AddUser form open in firebug and add an option:

```
<option value="superadmin">SuperAdmin</option>
```

Into the "role" drop-down, select it on the form, and upon submission, CakePHP will create a new SuperAdmin. So the best policy is still to not trust the client. The client is a pack of timberwolves and your server is a clutch of bunny-rabbits. Keep those two separate.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add the SecurityComponent to your AppController::$components variable to prevent the client from altering hidden fields.

Comment: Whilst this is a true statement, it misses the more important general point. The OP is correct to not trust client-side data; Every action in your controller must always validate that the user has permission to perform that action on the affected data before allowing it to happen. If the user doesn't own the data, or shouldn't be allowed to perform such an action upon it, reject the request.